# broken packages installing electric full on natty

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu-natty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ros-electric-ros-full on a natty machine and get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-electric-ros-full : Depends: ros-electric-rx (= 1.6.1-s1314989513~natty) but 1.6.1-s1314993028~natty is to be installed
```

Did apt-get update, and tried uninstalling and reinstalling ros-electric-rx to no avail.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11615/broken-packages-installing-electric-full-on-natty/) by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9115 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The repo is probably being updated.

Wait a while, then try updating and installing again.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-10-20**:
Three hours later still having the same issue. Can anyone from Willow confirm that the repo is/was being updated?